# CNF formula for manipulating words

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, satisfiability, combinatorics-on-words, conjunctive-normal-form

I am trying to create CNF formula for manipulation of a word.  word is a sequence of letters from a $\Sigma$ alphabet. A word is encoded by variables like $x_{i,a}$ which means that the letter $a$ is at position $i$.
So there is these two questions that I am interested in:

1. How to write a formula in CNF that expresses that the word does not contain any $b$ on it?
   So far I have come up with thise but I am not sure if it is true:
   $$\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \; (\bigvee_{b \in \Sigma}  \neg x_{i,b} )$$
2. How to write a formula (not necessarily in CNF) that expresses that the word has $abc$ on it in consecutive positions?
   I have come up with this but again I am not sure:
   $$\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-2} \; ((x_{i,a} \rightarrow x_{i+1,b}) \rightarrow x_{i+2,c})$$
   I would be appreciated if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is
$$\lnot \bigvee_{i=1}^n x_{i,b} = \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \lnot x_{i,b}$$

The second one is
$$\bigvee_{i=1}^{n-2} \left(x_{i,a} \land x_{i+1,b} \land x_{i+2,c}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could I ask why in the first formula, you have deleted the big disjunction? And also for second formula I also taught something that you wrote but isn't it correct the thing that I wrote?

Comment: Your first proposition is for a fixed $b$, so the formula should not include a disjunction over arbitrary $b$. Your second proposition is fundamentally a disjunction because you want $abc$ to appear in at least one position. Consider $ababc$, which is acceptable but does not satisfy your formula.